# Angular Web Application is loosing style for some users regularly

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm working on an application running on Angular and we do have some issues with the style of our app. Some of our users (me included) when they access our platform they don't have any sytle loaded. It's very contraining and a very poor user experience, specially when they receive an email which redirect them to our application and they need to see what is going on, when they click on the button in the mail to access the platform if the style is not loaded they will not reach the page the email send them, they will be redirected to the home page without any styling.

So, there is a workarround, if they refresh the page (simple refresh, shit+F5, CTRL+F5) the style will be loaded and they will be able to use our application without style issues anymore until they leave the app and comeback some time later and there will be no style again.

I had already read a lot of posts, articles to try to fix it, my team aswell and we were not able to solve this, here is a list of what we tried :

- Not keeping files cached in `nginx` configurations, to always have the latest deployed files
- Refreshing the application when there is a new release
- In `angular.json` setting "optimization" to true so it minifies css files and all ...
- Having `<base href="/" />` in the index.html files

Also, we do have **2 environments** for our application, "staging" app for pre-release, tests, etc... and "production". We have this issues **only on production**, even though the 2 platforms have similar configurations, how is it possible ?

We also figured out something, when we inspect the files in chrome "Sources" tab we see that in the style file there is HTML code **when** the style is missing.

Google Chrome does not show any errors but in Firefox we have those :

[image: Errors on Firefox about missing style]

And here is the content of the style file in Chrome "Sources" tab :

[image: Content of style file in browser source tab]

The content of our default.conf for nginx configurations looks like this :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        # kill cache
        expires -1;
        sendfile off;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
        if_modified_since off;
        etag off;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

This is the content of the nginx.conf running in the server, I do not know how I can edit this ? I don't have a file for this, it is generated automatically I think :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

We keep searching but could not manage to solve this until now, anyone has an idea about how to fix this and have the style always loaded ?

Angular version is 12.1.1

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your main `nginx.conf` file (not the one containing a `server` block`) should have `include mime.types;` line under `http` block. Or you can define MIME type for CSS files manually like `types { text/css css; }` under your `server` block.

Comment: I edited my post with the content of the `nginx.conf` file, but I don't think I can edit that file ? I had to access via shell the deployed app to find it, I do not have it localy

Comment: You're using the angular serviceWorker. On each deploy you have to increment the `"version"` value of your `ngsw-config.json`. This will re-download assets instead of retrieving them from the cache. Could you try that? [Example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json#L4)

Comment: When I try to put `"version": 1` field in the `ngsw-config.json` file VSCODE tells me that the property is invalid and I don't think that would help ? The service worker detects a new release is out by comparing the hashes off the generated files and if it sees changes it would load the new files

Answer (score 0):

Add this to youre server conf file:

```
location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
```

[More information about setting correct mime/types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types#how_to_set_up_your_server_to_send_the_correct_mime_types)

[More iformation about ngx_http_headers_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think that would help, as I said in the post the content of the style file I got comes with HTTP code, the issue is not about the mime types here I think

Comment: Create a file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder, name it css.conf, paste code and save, restart nginx. Its worth a try.